# Importing a text file into Postgres using ODBC

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, odbc, connection-string

I am trying to directly import a text file into Postgres, but using ODBC. I realize that this is a bit of an odd thing to do, but ODBC does a good job of fixing/ignoring errors in the text files and Postgres' Copy command is very, very picky. I use Copy when I can and ODBC where I can't.

I am currently doing this in two steps. ODBC Import to Access and then from Access to Postgres but I recently learned over [on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/00a1b60a-4e8b-4110-9f0e-cf0a54a9bcfd/my-schemaini-file-is-being-ignored-when-using-docmdtransfertext-from-net?forum=accessdev) I may be able to do this in one step but am having trouble with the SQL.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Dim TextConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=c:\PathToTextFile;Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No""")

Dim TextCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand

TextCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * INTO [ODBC;Driver={PostgreSQL};" & _
    " Server=server;Database=database;Uid=UserName;Pwd=Password;].[TableName] FROM [textfile.txt]", TextConnection)

TextCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I am getting this error: `Query input must contain at least one table or query.`

I am not where to go from here in debugging this. It also just might now be possible and that would be good to know.

Comment: Can you add a tag that shows which programming language you are using?

Comment: Added VB.NET tag.